# FileField does not upload files

Tags: python, django

please, drop me any advice. I will actually appreciate everything.
Whenever I succesfully pass the entire flow uploading a field with the usage of django-based web application, nothing really happen. Proper records are being inserted into the database, but files by itselves are not copied to the server's filesystem.

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.forms import ModelForm
from .choices import *
from .validators import validateExtensionOfTheFile
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class MusicFile(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    image = models.FileField(upload_to="music_images/%Y/%m/%d", null=True, blank=True, validators=[validateExtensionOfTheFile])
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from .choices import *
from .models import MusicFile

class MusicFileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MusicFile
        fields = '__all__'
        exclude = ('owner')

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MusicFileForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['image'].required = False
```

views.py

```
@login_required
def new_upload(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = MusicFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            post = form.save(commit=False)
            post.owner = User.objects.get(username=request.user.username)
            post.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/success/confirmed/')
    else:
        form = MusicFileForm()
    return render(request, 'new_upload.html', {'form': form})
```

new_upload.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Save</button>
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

@EDIT

setting.py:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        ...
        ...
        ...
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'django.template.context_processors.media',
            ],
        },
    },
]
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [...
]+ static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

@edit
Recently made mentioned changes to the code, but it still does not works as it should.
Anyway, I have took into an account the POST request that is being send to the server.
It is formulated in such a way:

```
csrfmiddlewaretoken=qDI7hZCzJYkqDSDnCCw3v3dG274Xb1NiYGWAMZhjgZxe4G3TXtY6EUmgtvjYLwOF&title=asdasd&image=Stromae+-+Alors+On+Danse+%28Dubdogz+Remix%29+%28Bass+Boosted%29.jpg
```

I am not certain whether this one is correct.
Shouldn'i it have been in the form of multipart/form-data?

Comment: can you post the template aswell?

Comment: so sorry for not doing so.
Just posted it

Comment: csrf_token must be in the form, ah i see you put it twice

Comment: ouh, alright. See it too :)
@edit
actually have changed it, but the result is the same : /

Comment: no i was referring in your template, csrf_token should always be inside <form></form>, but i didn't see you wrote it twice

Answer (score 0):

I was referrencing to the wrong template's name. The mistake has been made during the process of configurating the urlpatterns.
Thank you to all who have spent time on this problem.

Answer (score -1):

I can't see why it's not working in your fbv, but you can try with class based views:

```
class UploadMusicFile(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = MusicFile
    success_url = '/success/confirmed/'
    template_name = 'new_upload.html'
    form_class = MusicFileForm

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.owner = self.request.user
        return super(UploadMusicFile, self).form_valid(form)
```

Comment: Recently made mentioned changes to the code. Please, refer to the @edit located in the main post